# How do I change the dist-folder path in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, laravel, ember-cli

I would like to use ember-cli with Laravel and I need to know how I can change the path of the dist folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the output path option when using `ember build`:

```
ember build --output-path=/not-dist
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this command deletes everything in the dist folder. Is there any way this could be avoided?

Comment: It replaces the folder on each build. What's your desired behavior?

Comment: To have a clean build after each run. Don't store custom or vendor files in the dist folder. Use the public folder for this purpose.

Comment: Do you know if its posible to set that path somewhere else , like the config/environment.js?

Answer (score 39):

You can configure the output path by editing the .ember-cli file, which is located at the root of your project.

```
{
  "output-path": "my-output-folder/"
}
```

By default, this value is "dist/" for both 'build' and 'serve' commands, as you can see in the source code here:

https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/blob/0b7dcf3a0cdb35114643b076c91afda79efda6fc/lib/commands/build.js

https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/blob/0b7dcf3a0cdb35114643b076c91afda79efda6fc/lib/commands/serve.js

Answer (score -2):

You can also change the path from config/environment.js file ...

outside of the `module.exports = function(environment) { . . . }`

**`ENV.baseURL = '/your/new/path';`**